# Horizontal alignment in navbar

Tags: html, css

LATER EDIT: [This is how the logo looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdUdb.png)

EDIT: Removing the row class worked. Now I am trying to remove the gray background behind the logo image.

I am trying to align the logo with the rest of the text in the navbar (using bootstrap, but for some reason I fail to spot I cannot do that. The text items are correctly aligned between them, but the logo jumps on the higher row and is automatically aligned on center regardless of my definition.

Here is the code:

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://#">
              <img alt="Brand" src="img/logo_s.png">
           </a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-sm-8">
      <p> Play </p>
      <p> Learn </p>
      <p> Grow </p>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here's the result:
[how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVOTW.jpg)

Comment: where is your css?

Comment: If possible, create working snippet of your code.

Comment: The class "row" makes sure that you're starting on a new "row". So that's probably why it's not on the same row. I think you would like to have both in one row, so remove the class "row" and add it to, or under the "header"-tag.

Comment: because you use bootstrap, it's a high possibility that the problem is bootstrap's `!important` flags in its css, look for it in the dom inspector of your browser

Comment: The row class seems was the trouble maker. But how can I remove the gray background under the logo image?

Answer (score 0):

The css will be in one of the following classes

```
.navbar-header {
    background: #fff;
    border:0;
}
.navbar-header a {
    background: #fff;
    border:0;
}
```

If it doesn't change add !important before the semi-colon to force it to overwrite bootstrap.

Comment: It worked to some degree. Unfortunately it still keeps some sort of gray border which does not disappear even if I define the border as #fff. Thanks.

Comment: You need to inspect the element in the browser to locate where the border is being pulled from